# R sprintf maximum two decimals but no leading zeros

Tags: r, format, printf

As per the title, I need a string format where

```
sprintf(xxx,5)        prints "5"
sprintf(xxx,5.1)        prints "5.1"
sprintf(xxx,15.1234)  prints "15.12"
```

That is: no leading zeros, no trailing zeros, maximum of 2 decimals.

Is it possible? if not with sprintf, some other way?

The use case is to report degrees of freedom which are generally whole numbers, but when corrected, may result in decimals - for which case only I want to add two decimals).

Comment: `as.character(round(c(5, 5.1, 5.1234), 2))` returns `[1] "5"    "5.1"  "5.12"`

Comment: format(c(5, 5.1, 5.1234),digits = 0,nsmall = 2) does the same but will give you more options to define

Comment: that was simple using round. the format code actually returns "5.00" for me. how strange it seems impossible with sprintf though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe `formatC` is easier for this:

```
formatC(c(5, 5.1, 5.1234), digits = 2, format = "f", drop0trailing = TRUE)
#[1] "5"    "5.1"  "5.12"
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution based on `sprintf` as suggested:

```
sprintf("%.4g", 5)
#[1] "5"
sprintf("%.4g", 5.1)
#[1] "5.1"
sprintf("%.4g", 15.1234)
#[1] "15.12"
```

Verbose information to `sprintf` can be found e.g. here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/
which says:

> g | Use the shortest representation: %e or %f

and

> .number | ... For g and G specifiers: This is the maximum number of significant digits to be printed.

Comment: That satisfied the examples, but not the specifications, e.g. . `sprintf("%.4g",005.12345)` gives "5.123" whereas `sprintf("%.4g",135.12345)` gives "135.1".